# tidyverse_conflicts()

Tags: r, tidyverse

Ao carregar o pacote tidyverse, mostra que está havendo alguns conflitos.

```
-- Attaching packages --------------------------------------- tidyverse 
 1.2.1 --
v ggplot2 3.0.0     v purrr   0.2.5
v tibble  1.4.2     v dplyr   0.7.6
v tidyr   0.8.1     v stringr 1.3.1
v readr   1.1.1     v forcats 0.3.0
-- Conflicts ------------------------------------------ tidyverse_conflicts() - -
x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
x dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
```

Não tenho conseguido realizar plotar pontos em gráficos de dispersão. Será que tem alguma relação quanto a presença deste conflito?

Não consegui identificar o pacote que está gerando conflito com o Tidyverse.
O que devo fazer?

Comment: Estes conflitos são normais. Note que ele reporta que as funções `filter` e `lag` do pacote `dplyr` mascaram funções de mesmo nome do pacote `stats`. Pode ignorá-los. Quanto ao gráfico de dispersão, já tentou fechar e abrir o R sem salvar a área de trabalho para ver se a situação se conserta sozinha?

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Para completar o que o @MarcusNunes diz, quando há conflitos é melhor chamar funções na forma `pacote::função`. Por exemplo, `stats::lag(x, n)` ou `dplyr::lag(x, n)`. Neste caso, depois de carregar o pacote `tidyverse` se só fizer `lag(.)` será a função do pacote `dplyr` a ser chamada.